# iOS Crash related to javascript core, web thread

Tags: ios, javascriptcore, web-thread

getting lots of crashes in ios11 as below: webkit framework is included in project. any idea what could be reason for this crash ?

```
Crashed: WebThread
0  JavaScriptCore                 0x18bdbeebc bmalloc::Heap::allocateSmallChunk(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, unsigned long) + 680
1  JavaScriptCore                 0x18bdbec70 bmalloc::Heap::allocateSmallChunk(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, unsigned long) + 92
2  JavaScriptCore                 0x18bdbef58 bmalloc::Heap::allocateSmallPage(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, unsigned long, std::__1::array<bmalloc::List<bmalloc::SmallPage>, 112ul>&) + 152
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x18bdbf45c bmalloc::Heap::allocateSmallBumpRangesByObject(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, unsigned long, bmalloc::BumpAllocator&, bmalloc::FixedVector<bmalloc::BumpRange, 3ul>&, std::__1::array<bmalloc::List<bmalloc::SmallPage>, 112ul>&) + 52
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x18bdbd228 bmalloc::Allocator::refillAllocatorSlowCase(bmalloc::BumpAllocator&, unsigned long) + 160
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x18bdbd358 bmalloc::Allocator::allocateLogSizeClass(unsigned long) + 160
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x18bba1cec JSC::MarkedBlock::tryCreate(JSC::Heap&) + 36
7  JavaScriptCore                 0x18bba10c0 JSC::MarkedAllocator::allocateSlowCaseImpl(JSC::GCDeferralContext*, bool) + 368
8  JavaScriptCore                 0x18bce69d0 JSC::Subspace::allocate(unsigned long) + 152
9  JavaScriptCore                 0x18bcfb7a0 JSC::UnlinkedFunctionExecutable::link(JSC::VM&, JSC::SourceCode const&, std::optional<int>, JSC::Intrinsic) + 236
10 JavaScriptCore                 0x18b6c9b98 JSC::CodeBlock::finishCreation(JSC::VM&, JSC::ScriptExecutable*, JSC::UnlinkedCodeBlock*, JSC::JSScope*) + 1964
11 JavaScriptCore                 0x18bcb9f64 JSC::ScriptExecutable::newCodeBlockFor(JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSFunction*, JSC::JSScope*, JSC::JSObject*&) + 1088
12 JavaScriptCore                 0x18bcba384 JSC::ScriptExecutable::prepareForExecutionImpl(JSC::VM&, JSC::JSFunction*, JSC::JSScope*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::CodeBlock*&) + 240
13 JavaScriptCore                 0x18b454718 JSC::LLInt::setUpCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Instruction*, JSC::CodeSpecializationKind, JSC::JSValue, JSC::LLIntCallLinkInfo*) + 672
14 JavaScriptCore                 0x18bb9b444 llint_entry + 26996
15 JavaScriptCore                 0x18bb94900 vmEntryToJavaScript + 272
16 JavaScriptCore                 0x18ba73190 JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 184
17 JavaScriptCore                 0x18ba47af4 JSC::Interpreter::executeProgram(JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*) + 12168
18 JavaScriptCore                 0x18b7108e8 JSC::evaluate(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 340
19 WebCore                        0x18d77fe4c WebCore::ScriptController::evaluateInWorld(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&, WebCore::DOMWrapperWorld&, WebCore::ExceptionDetails*) + 324
20 WebCore                        0x18d786458 WebCore::ScriptElement::executeClassicScript(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&) + 584
21 WebCore                        0x18d4c5750 WebCore::LoadableClassicScript::execute(WebCore::ScriptElement&) + 164
22 WebCore                        0x18d7866fc WebCore::ScriptElement::executeScriptAndDispatchEvent(WebCore::LoadableScript&) + 216
23 WebCore                        0x18d78ce0c WebCore::ScriptRunner::timerFired() + 456
24 WebCore                        0x18c85b000 WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 172
25 WebCore                        0x18c85af40 WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 28
26 CoreFoundation                 0x1849fefc0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
27 CoreFoundation                 0x1849fece4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
28 CoreFoundation                 0x1849fe4e4 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
29 CoreFoundation                 0x1849fc0cc __CFRunLoopRun + 1928
30 CoreFoundation                 0x18491be58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
31 WebCore                        0x18c88ca34 RunWebThread(void*) + 560
32 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18467c2b4 _pthread_body + 308
33 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18467c180 _pthread_body + 310
34 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18467ab74 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: did you get the solution????

Comment: no, not yet....

Comment: Are you using YouTube Player in your app?

Comment: no, i am not using it, but i am displaying ads, which may be or may not be using it , no idea.