# ios - webthread- java script core crash

Tags: ios, javascriptcore, web-thread

getting lots of crashes as below in ios11: any idea what could be reason behind it. its happening in ios11 only. webkit framework is included in project.

```
Crashed: WebThread
0  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d513a2c bmalloc::Heap::allocateLarge(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 24
1  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d513a20 bmalloc::Heap::allocateLarge(std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::StaticMutex>&, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 12
2  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d5112a0 bmalloc::Allocator::allocateLarge(unsigned long) + 92
3  JavaScriptCore                 0x18cb6bef4 WTF::fastMalloc(unsigned long) + 112
4  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d11e6a8 JSC::Heap::addExecutable(JSC::ExecutableBase*) + 352
5  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d10a288 JSC::FunctionExecutable::finishCreation(JSC::VM&) + 48
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d44f7cc JSC::UnlinkedFunctionExecutable::link(JSC::VM&, JSC::SourceCode const&, std::optional<int>, JSC::Intrinsic) + 280
7  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d207860 JSC::functionPrototypeApplyCodeGenerator(JSC::VM&) + 64
8  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d10d81c JSC::FunctionPrototype::addFunctionProperties(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::JSFunction**, JSC::JSFunction**, JSC::JSFunction**) + 156
9  JavaScriptCore                 0x18d21a9f8 JSC::JSGlobalObject::init(JSC::VM&) + 1300
10 JavaScriptCore                 0x18d224898 JSC::JSGlobalObject::finishCreation(JSC::VM&, JSC::JSObject*) + 144
11 WebCore                        0x18e015590 WebCore::JSDOMGlobalObject::finishCreation(JSC::VM&, JSC::JSObject*) + 24
12 WebCore                        0x18e850840 WebCore::JSDOMWindowBase::finishCreation(JSC::VM&, WebCore::JSDOMWindowProxy*) + 44
13 WebCore                        0x18e7d28ac WebCore::JSDOMWindow::finishCreation(JSC::VM&, WebCore::JSDOMWindowProxy*) + 36
14 WebCore                        0x18e8548a4 WebCore::JSDOMWindowProxy::setWindow(WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::DOMWindow>&&) + 516
15 WebCore                        0x18eed505c WebCore::ScriptController::setDOMWindowForWindowProxy(WebCore::DOMWindow*) + 360
16 WebCore                        0x18dfed904 WebCore::FrameLoader::clear(WebCore::Document*, bool, bool, bool) + 476
17 WebCore                        0x18e3a42c8 WebCore::DocumentWriter::begin(WebCore::URL const&, bool, WebCore::Document*) + 368
18 WebCore                        0x18dfebb58 WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitData(char const*, unsigned long) + 176
19 WebKitLegacy                   0x18f3d3bd8 -[WebHTMLRepresentation receivedData:withDataSource:] + 112
20 WebKitLegacy                   0x18f3d3af8 -[WebDataSource(WebInternal) _receivedData:] + 68
21 WebKitLegacy                   0x18f3d3a98 WebFrameLoaderClient::committedLoad(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, char const*, int) + 112
22 WebCore                        0x18e0099c4 WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitLoad(char const*, int) + 172
23 WebCore                        0x18e008bec WebCore::DocumentLoader::continueAfterContentPolicy(WebCore::PolicyAction) + 1796
24 WebCore                        0x18e3930a0 WebCore::DocumentLoader::responseReceived(WebCore::ResourceResponse const&) + 1820
25 WebCore                        0x18e392004 WebCore::DocumentLoader::handleSubstituteDataLoadNow() + 308
26 WebCore                        0x18dfaf000 WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 172
27 WebCore                        0x18dfaef40 WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 28
28 CoreFoundation                 0x186152fc0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
29 CoreFoundation                 0x186152ce4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1861524e4 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
31 CoreFoundation                 0x1861500cc __CFRunLoopRun + 1928
32 CoreFoundation                 0x18606fe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
33 WebCore                        0x18dfe0a34 RunWebThread(void*) + 560
34 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185dd02b4 _pthread_body + 308
35 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185dd0180 _pthread_body + 310
36 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185dceb74 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Crash related to javascript core, web thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516384/ios-crash-related-to-javascript-core-web-thread)